# Eclipse Helios - "cannot run program make; unknown reason"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I upgraded Eclipse from Galileo to Helios, and when I try doing "Clean Project", I get an error saying "cannot run program make; unknown reason".  I was able to run make in Galileo, so I'm not sure why this is happening, and whether anyone else encountered this.

Comment: Is it a Java project or a C/C++ (CDT) one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add PATH to the environment (Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment).

I also had to add $ORACLE_HOME to the environment as well (my code uses Pro*C) - looks like CDT isn't picking-up the user's environment variables when it was before.

It's annoying, I know...

Comment: Applied for me using Momentics IDE 10.2 beta (Blackberry 10 development environment)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer that builds on trojanfoe's above.

Assuming you can run make in your native environment shell, the solution depends on whether you selected "Replace native environment with specified one" (OP1) or "Append variables to native environment" (OP2) in (Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment):

Solution-OP1: Add PATH to the environment (Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment).

I also had to add $ORACLE_HOME to the environment as well (my code uses Pro*C) - looks like CDT isn't picking-up the user's environment variables when it was before.

It's annoying, I know...

Solution-OP2: make sure the location of your make command in the PATH variable in your native environment.

Answer (score 0):

Some amplification on this helpful information for OS X that I discovered this evening with Helios:

my make was located in /Developer/usr/bin; I added this to the PATH variable.

In the C/C++ Build -- Settings section of the project preferences, I added the `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.skd/usr/lib` directory.  It includes the libraries you will need.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in project -> properties -> C/C++build -> Environment, "Append variables to native environment" has to be chosen instead of "Replace native environment with specified one".