# Eclipse Helios-"cannot run program 'make' : unknow reason" on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, osx-lion

I am a college undergraduate trying to learn C++ programming on my Macbook. It is installed with Mac OSX 10.7.3.

I have been trying to build the "hello world" project on Eclipse Helios, but after I clicked on the build project button, it keeps telling me "cannot run program 'make : unknow reason".

I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762578/eclipse-helios-cannot-run-program-make-unknown-reason) but it seems to be for the Windows OS instead of MAC OS, and I don't quite follow the instructions in it either (sorry I don't have any familiarity with programming...). The description for PATH variable is "not available" and I don't know if this is a problem. I'm also confused about what to put in the "Name" slot.

[image]

**Edit:**
Now after some trials I have "make" in my PATH. (i.e. the command line gives the information of the make after I input "make --version") and my PATH is set to

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

However the same problem still persists. Can anybody please help? Thank you!!

Comment: can you run make on the commandline?

Comment: @juanchopanza How should I do that? (sorry I know almost nothing about programming..)

Comment: start a terminal, and type `make --version`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did as you said and the feedback is "-bash: make: command not found"

Comment: So, either you don't have make installed, or it isn't in your path. You also need `g++` by the way.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see... Then how should I resolve it? I remember downloading Xcode from apple store, not sure if this would have out make in my computer already.

Comment: I'm not sure, I always installed everything independently of XCode. I used macports.org to get make, gcc and all that.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as `$PATH` is not the issue.  The issue is clearly that you don't have the correct tools installed. I would suggest installing macports for example, but I think that might be beyond your ability.

Comment: @trojanfoe I installed macports but it stil doesn't work

Comment: And is /opt/local/bin in your `$PATH`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have managed to add make into the PATH but the problem remains. Please see my update of the question

Comment: Are you sure that eclipse is using this `$PATH`?  One way to ensure this is to set it in your shell profile and logout and back in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Undeleted this answer as it turned out to be correct.

Yes, I'd say that `$PATH` was the problem.

Your system default version of `$PATH` should be sufficient and if not then set it correctly in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.  You'll need to logout and back in for these changes to take effect.  Doing this will mean that you can compile from the command line without going into eclipse, which is something you'll want to do at some point.

Now simply configure eclipse to avoid setting any build variables and all should be well.  Under Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Build Variables, the list should be empty:

[image]

Comment: My build variable list is empty, but it still doesn't work.. I don't quite follow your instruction in the second paragraph. How should I set them correctly in .profile or .bash_profile exacly?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to install Xcode (http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) from the App Stor (for Mac). Xcode is (free) developer tools supplied by Apple. After installing Xcode you can go to the menu 'Xcode' -> 'Open Developer Tools' -> 'More Developer tools' that will take you to apple developer site (where you probably have to register) and where you can download 'Command Line Tools for Xcode' that will contain make etc. for unix style development.

Xcode is quit nice and if there is no demand to use Eclipse when you could probably do well with Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @marcusg ! I also discovered that I didn't have the make installed because I didn't get the 'Command Line Tools'. But now that I have it installed already, eclipse still wouldn't run the make (I can access make from the terminal). Do you have any idea why that happened?

Comment: My guess is that you have a problem with your $PATH and/or Eclipse settings (where you set where the tools are located on disk). ...as @trojanfoe said in his answer.